# Get Facebook IDs of all contacts

Tags: facebook

How can I get the Facebook identifiers of all of my Facebook friends? I mean the numbers like 7843652532 or 93923423.

Either via an URL, a Facebook app, a browser extension, or anything.

Any format would be OK, for instance a text list or JSON.

*(I am using these IDs to associate with my address book, since many of my friends change names.)*

Comment: @Barry: Yes :-) Any format would be OK, for instance list or JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since December 2014 it is a bit complex:

- Install the FB Purity extension
- Load the Facebook homepage
- Find your `~/.config/chromium/Default/Local Storage/chrome-extension_ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl_0.localstorage` file. (exact name might vary, search for `ncdlagniojmheiklojdcpdaeepochckl` in your filesystem)
- Open this file with SQLitebrowser
- Select the data `ItemTable`>`oldfriendstore-<something>`
- It is the list of ID,name couples as JSON

---

**PRE-2014/12 method**

Barry's answer has worked great in the past, but that link is not available anymore. New solution: Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/friends select V1.0 and press Submit. You get the whole list of ID+name couples.

Answer (score 3):

You get this is JSON format by going to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

About the 4th paragraph you need to click the link next to "Friends" (which is https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends) however the link on the page includes an Authorization token which is require to run the query.

[image: Facebook Friends Link]

This will give a JSON result of all friends names and Facebook ID's

Comment: Impressive! Not need to write a request or authorize an application or anything :-)

Comment: The first link displays a page which has probably changed since 2011, now it does not have a "Friends" section. Would you mind updating? Thanks!